# Post Multiple Objects Inside Express Route

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to post multiple objects to my mongo database inside of an express route. Currently, everything is working fine when I do it as a single object (ie ONE casino), please see below, but instead of doing this a million times over, can someone help me do it as one giant data dump so I can post ALL my casinos?

Here is my route that works fine for posting a single object:

```
router.post('/post', async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
const casinoD = new Casino({
    casino: req.body.casino,
    table_and_other: req.body.table_and_other,
    poker: req.body.poker,
    slot_machines: req.body.slot_machines,
    total_gaming_win: req.body.total_gaming_win,
    year: req.body.year,
    month: req.body.month,
    combined_date: req.body.combined_date
})

try {
    const newCasino = await casinoD.save()
    res.status(201).json(newCasino)
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message})
}
})
```

I also understand mongoimport is a better way to do this - however that had its own issues in of itself.

Thanks

Comment: Implement the logic to handle the request being an array in addition to the single entry logic you have now. Something like `const casinos = req.body.casinos; for (let casino of casinos) { // build a single object here and save it to the db }`

Answer (score 0):

Like @JDunken said, you can iterate over the POST body as an array and insert in bulk. You'll want to use 
[insertMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) for speed. To insert millions of records, you will probably want to put a sane limit on the number of records per request, and send API requests in batches. Validation is optional, as Mongoose will run validation according to the schema. It depends on how you want to handle validation errors. Make sure to read up on the `ordered` and `rawResult` options for that as well.

```
router.post('/post', async (req, res) => {
  // you should sanity check that req.body is an array first, depending on how robust you want error handling to be
  const casinos = req.body.filter(input => isValid(input));

  try {
      const insertedCasinos = await CasinoModel.insertMany(casinos, { ordered: false });
      res.status(201).json(insertedCasinos)
  } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: err.message})
  }
})

const isValid(input) {
    let valid = true;
    // implement input validation
    return valid;
}
```